# How to add ssl certificate from keycloak application to java spring boot application?

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, ssl, keycloak

I have`keycloak`running inside a docker container with nginx https proxy.
Now I'm trying to connect spring boot with keycloak,
but I get an "ssl handshake" error

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

How can I add the valid certificate path to the requested target?

I tried to add a keystore and trust the certificate from keycloak inside the keystore.
But it doesn't work.

Comment: could you elaborate on "I tried to add a keystore and trust the certificate from keycloak inside the keystore." ?

Answer (score 0):

This issue has to do with the fact that this specific cert is not included in the trusted certificates store (JDK cacerts).

A Java KeyStore (JKS) can be created with this specific certificate with this command (keytool is contained in JDK bin folder):

```
keytool -importcert -file /path/to/certToTrust.cer -keystore truststore.jks -alias "certToTrust"
```

This command will generate a new JKS with the certificate in it. With this JKS we can provide it as a TrustStore in **application.properties**:

```
#server_ssl
server.ssl.key-store:file:/.../server_cert.p12
server.ssl.key-store-password:...
server.ssl.keyStoreType:pkcs12

#server_trust_store
server.ssl.trust-store=/.../truststore.jks
server.ssl.trust-store-password=...
server.ssl.trust-store-type=jks
```